# Selenium WebElement times out on most commands

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I've run into a problem that has baffled me while attempting to use Selenium 3.4 on jre 1.8 in JUnit. After successfully grabbing a WebElement, attempting to perform the click(), isDisplayed(), sendKeys(), and clear() functions all cause the driver connection to timeout before they can complete. I've wound up creating the following code:

```
@Test
public void canLogIn(){
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.get("http://"+ip+"/login/loginpage.html");
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("username_div"));
    System.out.println("Username to string: "+username.toString());

    /*Thread.sleep(6000);*/

    if(!username.isEnabled()) fail();

    if(!username.isDisplayed()) fail();

    username.click();
    username.clear();   
    username.sendKeys("manager");
```

...

So far, the code has timed out on username.isDisplayed(), username.click(), username.clear(), and username.sendKeys() when all the other elements were commented out. However, username.toString() works, and shows the correct element, and the code has yet to hang on username.isEnabled(). Thread.sleep() was used to test whether allowing the page to load would eliminate the issue, but to no avail. I have tried executing these commands using Selenium's JavascriptExecutor, also to no avail. I am well and truly stumped at this point, and any assistance you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the related HTML?

Comment: Are you familiar with the WebDriverWait class and it's until() method?  If not, then go read up on it and figure out how to apply it here.

Comment: Your WebElement username has an id = "username_div".  Is this really a DIV element?  I wonder if you can even do a "clear" or "sendKeys" to such a control.  Perhaps you need to find the input field within that div and target these actions to that WebElement?

Answer (score 0):

Is the username element visible? Perhaps you can try adding this after opening the page:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated("username_div"));
```

What exception are you getting if any?